# Google analytics Referrer Campaign

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to add the Referrer Campaign analytics in my app, i have gone through the following [links](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-implement) [links](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/CampaignTrackingReceiver.html)

Do I need to just add the following declaration in the manifest

**OR**

**I need to create my own receiver to handle the task of sending my referrer data to google analytics??**

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

PLease help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the service and the receiver definition to your application manifest. The implementation for both is provided by the Google Play Services library.